# FAIL - Application at context path /openrdf-sesame could not be started

Tags: java, tomcat, sesame

I am quite new Java Sesame and am having some difficulties to get started. I am using mac 10.5.8. For configuration, I was supposed to deploy two `war` files in the Tomcat server Manager: `/openrdf-workbench` and `/openrdf-sesame`. The `/openrdf-workbench` file was deployed successfully. Unfortunately the `/openrdf-sesame` was not deployed. I have received the following message:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /openrdf-sesame could not be started
```

When I run the Tomcat Server, I received the following:

```
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /apache-tomcat-7.0.32/wtpwebapps/openrdf-sesame does not exist or is not a readable directory
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /apache-tomcat-7.0.32/wtpwebapps/openrdf-sesame does not exist or is not a readable directory
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Dec 16, 2013 12:16:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
    Dec 16, 2013 12:16:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error getConfigured
    Dec 16, 2013 12:16:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/openrdf-sesame] startup failed due to previous errors
    Dec 16, 2013 12:16:23 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase stop
    INFO: The stop() method was called on component [WebappLoader[/openrdf-sesame]]      after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
    Dec 16, 2013 12:16:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

I do not know how to solve this issue. Besides, I do not know what the next step can be. Could anyone please help me solve these two issues. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Post the rest of the start up logs.

Comment: Sorry about this question. What did you mean with the start up logs?

Comment: Tomcat logs the various steps it takes to launch a web application. If something went wrong, it will have logged what it can. Find those logs and post the relevant parts.

Comment: I hope I got it right.

Comment: That looks like it. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /apache-tomcat-7.0.32/wtpwebapps/openrdf-sesame does not exist or is not a readable directory` Find out if the directory actually exists and if it is readable from the user that starts tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `apache-tomcat-7.0.32`. It seemed it did not suit `Mac 10.5.8` and `Java 1.6`. I installed `apache-tomcat-6.0.37`. The deployment of both files was successful.